# How to copy the text of an input, which is not in the html code with selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem with a input, because its value do not store in html code.

This is the html code

```html
<input spellcheck="false" class="editablesection" onkeypress="checkKey(event)" oninput="writinginput(this, 0)" maxlength="11" style="width: 113px;" readonly="">
```

[Image of input with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4vNA.png)

I search the element with this:

```
input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".editablesection")
```

But i cant copy the text because its not store in html code.

How i can do it?

Site where input its located:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/exercise.asp?filename=exercise_html_tables6

You need to click "Show Answer" button to see the text i want to copy.

Comment: This html is partial. If you can share the link of the site, can help

Comment: See it i edited the post.

Comment: Which text do you want to copy? There is no text.

Comment: Click show answer button and see the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use selenium `get_attribute("value")` method to extract the value.
Below is the code from selenium python:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://www.w3schools.com/html/exercise.asp?filename=exercise_html_tables6')
driver.maximize_window()
sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Show Answer')]").click()
sleep(3)
readOnlyField = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#showcorrectanswercontainer > .editablesection")
print(readOnlyField.get_attribute("value"))
driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
rowspan="2"
```

Comment: _`rowspan`_ is the attribute name with a value of _**`2`**_, how did you get it by `get_attribute("value")`

Comment: This work perfectly! Thanks! But there is one thing that I don't know yet. Where is this data stored?. Im new programming and i am learning :)

Comment: @DebanjanB That's not the case here. It's a text field only, which stores "rowspan=2" as a value that can get stored by clicking the Show Answer button. Which later can get extracted by getAttribute("value")

Comment: @QualityMatters Good catch +1